# menu bar JavaScript and file level issue

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created a responsive menu bar as show in attached images, it working fine in files level as below:
[image]

https://airlineshq.com/airlines/malaysia/index.htm

when go further 1 level down,

[image]

https://airlineshq.com/airlines/malaysia/airasia/index.htm

the responsive menu bar still working but the search icon, hamburger 3 row bar and X bar never appear. I believe is due to file structure issue, anybody can assist to check?

help to check on the script below to identify whether any issue?

```
<div class="navbar" id="nav">
      <a href="https://airlineshq.com" class="active">Home</a>
     <a href="../../../passenger_guides/index.htm">Passenger Guides</a>
      <a href="../../../airlines/index.htm">Airlines Offices</a>
      <a href="../../../lounges/index.htm">Lounges</a>

      <form class="search-box" action="search.htm">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search..">
    <button type="submit" class="search-icon"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
    
  </form>
    
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>  
</div>
</div>

<script>
    function myFunction() {
      var x = document.getElementById("nav");
      
      console.log(barIcon)
      if (x.className === "navbar") {
        x.className += " responsive";
        var barIcon = document.getElementsByClassName('fa-bars')[0];
        barIcon.classList.add("fa-times");
        barIcon.classList.remove("fa-bars");
      } else {
        var closeIcon = document.getElementsByClassName('fa-times')[0];
        closeIcon.classList.remove("fa-times");
closeIcon.classList.add("fa-bars");
        x.className = "navbar";
      }
    }  
</script>
```

Comment: How are you loading fontawesome?

Comment: i don't have fontawesome.css located in my directory. So, i don't think this is an issue.

Comment: problem resolved after added in <link rel="stylesheet" href="use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.13.0/css/all.css">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One level down may not have the right path to fontawesome

Top level:
`<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../fontawesome.ccs" />`

Next Level
`<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../../fontawesome.ccs" />`

Comment: problem resolved after added in <link rel="stylesheet" href="use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.13.0/css/all.css">

Comment: i'm just saying if you look at index.htm in malaysia folder and then index.htm in airasia folder, then make sure airasia's reference to fontawesome css is backing up one more level to where malaysia is referencing.  Of course, this is *ONLY IF* they aren't both referencing some sort of root/site-wide css folder directly... just throwing out ideas

Comment: OK.. just saw that you resolved it by adding in missing ref to fontawesome